# Symfony4: How to recieve data from linked entity?

Tags: symfony, symfony4

- Orders *// orders*
- Comments *// comments for every order*

**I would like to find latest comment written in this order.**

My

**Controller:**

```
 $orders = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Orders::class)->findAll();

  foreach($orders as $order) {  
     $temp = array(
         $order->getId(),
         $order->getComments()->findLatest( $order->getId() )
```

**Entity (Comments):**

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Orders", inversedBy="comments")
 */
private $orders;
```

**Entity(Order):**

```
/**
 * @return Collection|Comment[]
 */
public function getComments(): Collection
{
    return $this->comments;
}
```

**Comment Repository:**

```
public function findLatest($value)
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('c')
        ->andWhere('c.orders = :val')
        ->setParameter('val', $value)
        ->orderBy('c.id', 'DESC')
        ->setMaxResults(1)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult()
    ;
}
```

But looks like it not working in this way :(

**Error:**

```
Attempted to call an undefined method
named "findLatest" of class "Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection".
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? What happens when you call `getComments`- what is **really** returned there?

Comment: @NicoHaase Thank you for your comment: Attempted to call an undefined method named "findLatest" of class "Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection".

Comment: So, what makes you think that you can call `findLatest` on a collection? Have you written such a method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are trying to call a repository function from another entity

try to change this line :

```
 $order->getComments()->findLatest( $order->getId()
```

with:

```
 $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Comments::class)->findLatest($order->getId);
```

a better soulution will be that you work with $orders->getComments() array to avoid requesting data from the database inside a loop

Comment: It works! Perfect. Thank you very much for your support. I will use it this way. However not clear for me why does it marked in documentation and entity relation creation proccess an ability to access it directly:

 Do you want to add a new property to Category so that you can access/update
getProducts()? (yes/no) [yes]:
> yes  
https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/associations.html

Comment: of course you have direct access on it when you do $order->getComments() you will get all the comments belongs to the order. and you can get the last comment from the array in this case

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using the class `Doctrine\Common\Collections\Criteria`.

**Entity(Order):**

```
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Criteria;

...

  /**
   * Returns the latest comment or false if no comments found under that criteria
   */ 
  public function findLatestComment()
  {
    $criteria = Criteria::create()
      ->orderBy(array("id" => Criteria::DESC))
    ;

    return $this->getComments()->matching($criteria)->first();
  }
```

And then you can simply use it like this:

```
$order->findLatestComment();
```

Comment: Thank you for your support. It looks really simple and works perfect!

Comment: @szerz I updated my answer since I made a mistake. I hope it works well now!

Comment: Thank you. It works perfect! Appreciate your  support!